# CSS grid single column with max-width

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Using CSS grid, I would like to have a single, centred column with a max-width of 1024px.

Here's how I'm currently doing it.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.grid__content {
  max-width: 1120px; /* To make the content size 1024px, 96px is added to account for padding */
  width: 100%;
  padding: 48px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse nunc nunc, viverra quis varius et, iaculis condimentum odio. Sed sed commodo massa. Nulla a facilisis quam. Praesent sed nisl arcu. Aenean justo ante, eleifend at aliquet a, congue sit amet ipsum. Integer nunc ligula, tincidunt vel augue vel, pretium ultrices est. Aliquam non risus varius, pretium ex et, eleifend est. Suspendisse pretium urna velit, quis ultricies lacus porta nec. Nullam aliquet elit vitae dolor molestie, sed tristique diam vehicula. Phasellus volutpat placerat nunc.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can the same layout be achieved with `grid-template-columns` instead of the properties I've set on `.grid__column`?

Comment: unfortunately, you have to set max width on your 'grid__column' div

Comment: I thought that might be the case, thank you 